# Can't change volume in Windows Messenger

Tags: windows-xp, audio, windows-live-messenger

Recently in Windows Live Messenger, I can no longer change the volume during a voice/webcam call.  The volume for both me and my other party are set to off (not muted), and cannot be moved.

Other sounds on the system work just fine.

[image]

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

http://forums.techguy.org/all-other-software/559464-windows-live-messenger-problem.html

mutso wrote

If you start a voice chat instead of the video conversation, it will enable the sound.

The big step as mentioned in an earlier post is enabling the video.

In version 8.1 of messenger, you BOTH need to press the little camera icons below your profile pictures to enable the video (this is after the audio is connected)!

...... the normal video conversation only does video with no audio.

courseiam wrote
Try unticking "Click here if you are using headphone"... it worked for me

poltroon wrote
This is a known problem with messenger and Vista, and you can resolve it using this work around:

1. Start a voice call only; the sliders should then be active
2. Request the other persons webcam once voice is active.
3. When you can see their cam, send your own.

Comment: That's the first thing I found on google myself.  But 1) that doesn't seem to correspond with my version of Messenger. 2) It doesn't work.

Comment: @Flimzy perhaps worth trying another other party that is normally fine?

Comment: I've tried with three different people--one who doesn't even have a webcam, which means I was only able to try voice with them, which I think further demonstrates that the above fix doesn't work in my case. :(

Comment: @Flimzy worth trying asking here also http://windowslivehelp.com/forums.aspx?productid=2